# Get text() from Widget in Layout

Tags: qt, widget, children

I have created widgets from code for the first time instead of through the creator. It reads in a text file and fills a QScrollArea widget with the material name (checkbox to enable it or not) and the thickness lineEdit, as seen in the picture. The number of widgets made corresponds to the number of entries in the text file.

I create the pushbuttons and checkboxes using the following function:

```
void overlayers::newField(QString material, bool checked, double thickness)
{
    //Create new checkbox.
    QCheckBox * checkbox = new QCheckBox(material);
    checkbox->setChecked(checked);

    //Create new field.
    QLineEdit * line = new QLineEdit(QString::number(thickness));

    //Create horizontal layout.
    QHBoxLayout * layout = new QHBoxLayout();
    layout->addWidget(checkbox,Qt::AlignLeft);
    layout->addWidget(line,Qt::AlignRight);

    //Add horizontal layout to vertical.
    scrollLayout->addLayout(layout);
}
```

Where QVBoxLayout scrollLayout is defined in the class header.

I realised after doing the whole dialog box, I have to get the values from the fields and the checkbox flags to save the data but I have no idea how to iterate through all the checkboxes and lineEdits to get the text() and checkedState() variables!

I feel I have programmed this incorrectly and that there is a better way to do it. Is it possible to do this with how I have done it? If not, how would a better programmer do it re: creating the variable number of widgets and being able to access their data? A QVector sort of thing?

Thanks heaps!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKJVW.png

Comment: Using `QList` or `QVector` here is a common practice. Though you can iterate layout's children.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Amartel I would assume make two QVectors: QVector<QPushButton*> pushButtons and QVector<QCheckBox*> checkboxes to keep track of these guys?

Comment: You can either use two (or more) containers, or - create a struct, which contains all needed pointers for one line and, maybe, some additional information - whatever you find more convenient.